# Third party code on subdomain

Tags: cookies, xmlhttprequest, subdomain, xss

As the owner of domain example.com with many content what security risks arising from providing subdomain to third party company. We don't want to share any of the content and the third company would have complete control over the application and machine hosting the subdomain site.

I'm concerned mainly about:

1. Shared cookies

We have cookies .example.com, so there will be sent also in the requests to subdomain. Is it possible for us to point A record to reverse proxy where we strip the cookies and send the request to third party provider without them?

2. Content loading from main domain

Is it possible to set document.domain to example.com and do XMLHttpRequest to the example.com?

3. Cross site scripting

I guess that it would be no problem because of the same origin policy. Subdomain is treated as separate domain?

Any other security issues?

Comment: yes, subdomain is different, as is even just a port number change. page at `example.com:80` can't do a request to `example.com:8080`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We have cookies .example.com, so there will be sent also in the
>   requests to subdomain. Is it possible for us to point A record to
>   reverse proxy where we strip the cookies and send the request to third
>   party provider without them?

Great idea, you could do this yes, however you will also need to set the [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) flag, otherwise they would be able to retrieve them with JavaScript.

> Is it possible to set document.domain to example.com and do
>   XMLHttpRequest to the example.com?

No, subdomains for Ajax are treated as a different Origin. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15689311/413180).

> I guess that it would be no problem because of the same origin policy.
>   Subdomain is treated as separate domain?

JavaScript code could interact with each other subdomains - but only with the cooperation of your site. You would also need to also set `document.domain = 'example.com';` If you do not do this, you are secure against this threat.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin):

> When using document.domain to allow a subdomain to access its parent
>   securely, you need to set document.domain to the same value in both
>   the parent domain and the subdomain. This is necessary even if doing
>   so is simply setting the parent domain back to its original value.
>   Failure to do this may result in permission errors.

---

> Any other security issues?

You need to be aware of cookie poisoning. If `evil.example.com` sets a non [host-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28320172/413180) cookie at `.example.com` that your domain believes it has set itself, then the evil cookie may be used for your site.

For example, if you display the contents of the cookie as HTML, then this may introduce [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). Also, if you're using the [double submit cookies CSRF prevention method](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie) an evil domain may be able to set their own cookie value to achieve CSRF. See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/59512/8340).